What hat did Lightning Hopkins wear on the cover of the "Texas Blues Man" album?
For some blues history work I'm doing, I want to determine the style of this hat:

It seems to have some characteristics of a fedora or a trilby, but none of the images I've seen on various hat sites quite match what Lightning Hopkins is wearing. Note the absence of any curl-up on the brim, and the pinch in the crown is toward the back rather than front.
Here's the description of the album on Wikpedia.

Felt hats can be changed in shape using steam, which also helps adjust the size slightly. Could just be a backwards fedora with no brim curl.

That is a fedora, and the gentleman is wearing it backwards.

Do you have any reasons for saying it's a backwards fedora rather than a backwards trilby?

Because it's a backwards fedora, by my observation, and in my opinion.
It could technically be a backwards Trilby, but that is not my instictive response.

A gentleman who actually knew Lightnin' Hopkins called it a porkpie hat.
https://pleasekillme.com/lightnin-hopkins/

I think this is a Pork pie hat.   Popular among musicians, including Frank Sinatra.  
